# If a child has a class of active then give parent an active class too - Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

As the title says, I'm trying to give a parent nav item an `'is-active'` class if its child has an `'active'` class in `vanillaJS`. I know how to do it in `jQuery` but I'm not wanting to add them in my project going forward.

I've managed to create a basic jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/1k9su6vo/ - which is working how I intend it but I think it's a little too basic for when I start adding more complexity to the `nav`.

Is there a simple way to traverse the nav like `jQuery` does with `.find()`, `.closest()` etc but with js?

```
if (document.querySelector('.active')) {
   document.querySelector('.active').parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.classList.add('is-active');
}
```

Comment: TBH, if this is how you are going to go about it I don't think you will beat jQuery in speed and efficiency - jQuery is mature library that many have improved for years. There is no quick way to do this with Vanilla JS, and you have to adjust your thinking a bit so your thought go down the tree, never up.

Comment: If you're targeting recent browser then use [`Element#closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest). If not, then implement one, it won't be that hard to do, and use it instead of chaining `.parentNode` yourself.

Comment: There's a polyfill on that page that shows you how to do it for older browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to traverse the nav like jQuery does with
>   .find(), .closest() etc but with js?

Yes. [The Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method.

In your case, you want to add the `is-active` class on an immediate list item of the root list.

To make things easier, you can add a class to the root , eg: `.wpr`, to make immediate list items from the root easier to target:

```
document.querySelector('.active').closest('.wpr > li').classList.add('is-active');
```

```js
if (document.querySelector('.active')) {
  document.querySelector('.active').closest('.wpr > li').classList.add('is-active'); 
}
```

```css
.is-active > a {
  color: green;
}

li {
  color: black;
}

.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wpr">
  <li><a href="">test</a></li>
  <li><a href="">test2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">sub1</a></li>
      <li><a class="active" href="#">sub2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">sub3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">test3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

Modern browsers actually support .closest() method
see [Mozilla developer site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

Comment: Interesting. New stuff every day.

Answer (score 0):

To check if child `node` contains a specific `className` we can use

`.classList.contains('active');` which returns boolean.

**Working example:**

```js
if (document.querySelector('.active')) {
   document.querySelector('.active').parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.classList.add('is-active');
}

const node = document.querySelector('.child');
const parentNode = node.parentNode;
const trigger = document.getElementById('trigger');
trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const hasActiveClass = node.classList.contains('active');

  if (hasActiveClass) {
    parentNode.classList.add('active');
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  I am parent
  <div class="child active"> I am child</div>
</div>

<button id="trigger" type="button">trigger active</button>
```